# Query to get only cars inside car park

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, report

I want to do a report from a car park, and with this car park get the cars that are inside at the moment when i call the query.

Supose that we have two entrances and two exits, how i can do in SQL to get only cars inside that parking.

How I can get this values?

Example of records of my table:

```
id  lic plate   date                     lane    access id_user
__________________________________________________________________
10  1234-BK     2020-08-11 12:24:00.000    1     OK      4
11  1234-BK     2020-08-11 12:25:00.000    3     OK      4
```

With that example we supose that this car is out of the car park because lane 1 is from entrances and lane 3 is from exit, so the last record we have is from a exit lane.

With this information could you orientate me to do this query that get all the cars inside?

Comment: And how does one know if a car is inside or outside?  You should be recording the *direction* of the car.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Because lane 1 is from entrance, and lane 3 is to go outside. So if we have a record with lane 1 we know that car is inside, but in this case the last record is from lane 3, so the car is outside

Comment: But you have two entrances and two exits and you have only mentioned two lanes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be storing whether cars are entering or leaving.  That seems pretty basic for such an application.

If you don't have that, you can count the number of records up to a given time and if the value is odd the car is in and even it is out.  So to get the cars inside:

```
select lic_plate
from t
where date < @date
group by lic_plate
having count(*) % 2 = 1;
```

If you have entrance and exit lanes, you can get the last record using a correlated subquery and check for the final lance:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date)
                from t t2
                where t2.lic_plate = t.lic_plate and
                      t2.date < @date
               ) and
      t.lane = 1;  -- last lane is an entrance lane
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, following your instructions, with the column date which i need to show it in the report, i got all the values. And with the second option you gived me if i add on t.lane = 1 and t.lane = 2, i got more values which are not correct. But i still investigating thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get rows where the last 'lane' for each 'lic_plate' is lane 1 the OP could use a windowing function.

```
;with get_max_cte as (
    select t.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by lic_plate order by t.[date] desc) rn)
select * from get_max_cte
where rn=1 and lane=1
```